Related records get updated one delete later in Record Triggered flow for delete action
I have made a record triggered flow for delete context. I am fetching a procedure record. Procedure is the detail and Account Performance is the master. Whenever I delete a procedure record, I fetch other related records of the Account Performance (related to the deleting record), perform some calculation, assign these related procedure records with the new value and update the list. What's happening is, whenever I delete one record, nothing happens although the flow runs successfully. But when I delete the second record, the value gets updated as per the deletion of the first record which was deleted.


Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful. An image of the flow might be Minimal but it's neither Complete not Reproducible.

Unless you are excluding the deleted record from the 'Fetch Account Related Procedures' node, you'll actually be doing the calculation on the current list of records (before the Procedure record is deleted) which includes the current record.
To exclude the record that is being deleted from the Get Records node, you need explicitly filter out the deleted record by using something like the following:

Note I'm using Contact as the record being deleted, rather than a custom object as per your exact configuration but the concept is the same.

I have added this condition in my Get Records element. So that should not be the issue.
